# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database may be already in use: null. Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode [90020-193]

Tags: java, database, h2

I want to use H2 database in embedded mode and not on server mode.
But after only one transaction I am getting error that file is locked.
I have tried appending `DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE;FILE_LOCK=NO` after url but it is not working.

Is there any solution for this?

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <!-- <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:./test;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE</property> -->
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:./test;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE;FILE_LOCK=NO</property>
        <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="connection.password">sa</property>
```

here is the code that saves user object.

```
    SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure("/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    UserVO user = new UserVO();
    user.setUserId("4");
    user.setUserName("Fourth User");
    session.save(user);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.clear();
    session.close();
```

Comment: Please post at least the code that initializes the database and the connection

Comment: were you able to solve the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

just append ";AUTO_SERVER=TRUE" to your JDBC url to use the automatic mixed mode.
the first connection is embedded, and all subsequent connections are in tcp mode.